# Search for item in list of lists with Perl

Tags: perl

To find out if item is in array or list I use smart-match `~~` operator. But that works just for simple array/list to find out if such item is present or not. Is there a similar way to use this operator for the list of lists? List is sorted by first column. As the size is pretty large, I am looking for some core solution, the most effective, the fastest. Additionally the value of the second column should be returned.

---

Example of the list, first column has unique values, sorted:

```
my $list = [
             [ 'alpha' , 'item X' ],
             [ 'beta'  , 'item Q' ],
             [ 'gama'  , 'item C' ],
             ...
           ];
```

...searching for `'beta'` comes with result `'item Q'`, searching for `'omega'` comes with result `undef`.

Comment: how large is pretty large?

Comment: write some code and time it; if it is too slow, then worry about the fastest way.  almost any way you loop through 2000 elements will take no perceptible amount of time.

Comment: @ysth - it is about 2000 for now, but I am expecting the size grow, so I would better have code optimized, so it does not have to be changed later

Comment: if there were a million, it would still likely be less than a tenth of a second.  first, have a speed problem; only then optimize for speeed.

Comment: @ysth - Which is too long, as my script needs to complete within 10 milliseconds and this search is just a fraction of the code.

Comment: then if you have a million, you are likely out of luck

Comment: @ysth - Not really, with `O(log2 n)` it is just up to 20 iterations...

Comment: well, now that you tell us it is sorted by the column you are searching, yes :)

Comment: Some reason you don't use a hash instead for searching? That'll be *much* faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with the following structure/data:

```
my $list = [
              [ "alpha" , "X" ],
              [ "beta"  , "Q" ],
              [ "gama"  , "Z" ],
              [ "delta" , "C" ],
           ];

my $str = "gama";
```

I found the following solution very fast:

```
my ($min, $max, $pos, $cmp) = (-1, $#{$list} + 1, undef, -1);
while (($cmp != 0) && (($max - $min) > 1)) {
  $cmp = $str cmp ${$list}[$pos = int(($min + $max) / 2)][0];
  ($min, $max) = ($cmp > 0) ? ($pos, $max) : ($min, $pos);
}

return ($cmp == 0) ? ${$list}[$pos][1] : undef;
```

Comment: I would be very careful here.  Implementing a binary search is notoriously hard to do exactly right.  The version on wikipedia has several small differences from yours which should be concerning.

Comment: @woolstar - Can you please be more specific regarding risk you see in my solution? More further, it would be nice if you publish your own solution, so I can test it and consider it, if works well and fast enough.

Comment: The risk in your solution is that you may not have all the edge cases of binary search implemented right.  For instance the example on wikipedia sets `($min,$max) = ($cmp > 0) ? ($pos +1, $max) : ($min, $pos-1)` but also tests for equality inside the loop and returns directly.  My solution using a hash is below.

Comment: @woolstar - I don't see any problem/risk in my solution. In my code, `$min` and `$max` are outer boundaries, with need to test anything inside. My code has more efficiency `O(log2 n)`, compared to your code `O(n)`, so with million of records in the list, your code will do million iterations, my code up to 14.

Comment: If `$list` changes as often as searches happen, then a binary search is the best solution.  If `$list` is fixed, then a hash may out perform a binary search as its implementation is not a simple binary tree.

Comment: Looking up values in a hash is amortized `O(1)`. So if you look up many values, building a hash is quite likely better (for some value of *many*).

Comment: @amon - It may be `O(1)` for lookup, but `O(n)` for hash to build. For size of million records, you would need to perform over 70,000 lookups to reach efficiency of `O(log2 n)` solution, which is very unlikely.

Comment: @amon - My fault, not `14`, but `20`, sorry :) Yes, there is `k` factor, but it should not effect it that much. Anyway, it is good to have alternative solution from @woolstar to be listed here, so it can helps someone who face more lookups.

Answer (score 1):

This code works…

```
my @array = (
         [ 'alpha' , 'item 1' ],
         [ 'beta'  , 'item 2' ],
         [ 'alpha' , 'item 3' ],
        );
say 'beta' ~~ @array ? "yep" : "nope"; #=> yep
```

… because smartmatch recurses: `SCALAR ~~ ARRAY` smart-matches against each entry of the array until one succeeds. As it happens, the elements of the outer array are arrays themselves, so the same thing happens again.

Of course, you shouldn't use smartmatch. `use List::MoreUtils qw< any >` instead:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw< any >;

my @array = (
         [ 'alpha' , 'item 1' ],
         [ 'beta'  , 'item 2' ],
         [ 'alpha' , 'item 3' ],
        );

if (any { any { 'beta' eq $_ } @$_ } @array) {
  say "yep";
}
else {
  say "nope";
}
#=> yep
```

This is rather ugly, but `any` should be more efficient than `grep` (which you can use here equivalently). Unlike smartmatch, these solutions won't do sneaky unexpected things like recursing or executing coderefs -.-

---

If you want to get the “other” entry:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw< any firstval >;

my @array = (
         [ 'alpha' , 'item 1' ],
         [ 'beta'  , 'item 2' ],
         [ 'alpha' , 'item 3' ],
        );
if (my $array = firstval { any { 'beta' eq $_ } @$_ } @array) {
  my $other_item = firstval { 'beta' ne $_ } @$array;
  say "yep: $other_item";
}
else {
  say 'nope';
}
#=> yep: item 2
```

Comment: What if `'beta'` will be present also in second column?

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ Just run the code and see what happens :) None of the solutions here care at which position the element you are searching for will be found.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution (after edit) works with linear search. If `@array` would be sorted, better solution and performance can be delivered, I believe...

Answer (score 1):

If `$list` is fixed for multiple queries, then build a map of the key value:

```
# do this only when $list changes
my %listvalues= map { $_->[0], $_ } @$list ;

...

sub lookup
{
  my ($key)= @_ ;
  return (exists $listvalue{$key} ) ? $listvalues{$key}[1] : undef ;
}
```

Comment: This solution is way slow, as building a hash is `O(n)`

Comment: If `$list` is fixed, then this solution is `O(1)` for lookup.

Answer (score 0):

The `~~~` operator or Smart Match should work on a two dimensional array.

This is the most effective way that I can think of to see if an item is in an array other then looping through the array.

#### EDIT:

Please see the first comment on my response. It appears to be experimental and is recommended to move away from smart matching. I was unaware until the comment post was made. My apologies.

Comment: As of 5.18, [smart match is experimental](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.18.0/pod/perldelta.pod#The_smartmatch_family_of_features_are_now_experimental): *"It is clear that smartmatch is almost certainly either going to change or go away in the future. Relying on its current behavior is not recommended."*

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for the tip. I was unaware of this!